# tool to export YouTube video with its chapters

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I want to download YouTube video along with its chapters. Chapters should be embedded as a bookmark in downloaded video. Is there a tool or way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) just execute:

```bash
yt-dlp --embed-chapters "VIDEO_ID"
```

Note that the video download is far more slow with the argument `--embed-chapters`.